# Actualizar datos en la Misma Tabla

Tags: mysql

Tengo la tabla `adm_products` en donde guardo los datos de **productos y componentes**, en la imagen se pueden ver dos productos y un componente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En otra tabla `adm_products_components` guardo los componentes de cada producto con sus respectivas cantidades

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El `prd_pricecost` del producto es la `SUM(adm_products_components.prd_comp_qty * adm_products.prd_pricecost)` de todos los componentes que pertenecen al Producto.

En el evento que se cambie el `prd_pricecost` del componente o se elimine el componente se debe recalcular el `prd_pricecost` de todos los productos que lo contienen para lo cual estoy haciendo esta consulta...

```
UPDATE adm_products 
SET 
    prd_pricecost = (SELECT 
            SUM(prd_comp_qty * prd_pricecost) AS totalCost
        FROM
            adm_products_components
                INNER JOIN
            adm_products ON prd_comp_prd_id = prd_id
        WHERE
            prd_comp_comp_id = 28);
```

Lo que pretendo en esta consulta es actualizar el `prd_pricecost` de todos los productos que contengan el componente 28 pero mysql no lo permite.

Como debo hacer la consulta?

Answer (score 1):

lo primero que tengo que resaltar es que no estas calculando bien el costo.
antes de hacer el update debes asegurarte que el valor que vas a actualizar es correcto.

Para asegurarme de ayudarte con precisión repliqué tus tablas en una bd propia pero con nombres mas faciles. estos son :

```
create table products(

id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY ,
name varchar (60),
price decimal (9,2),
cost  decimal (9,2)
)



create table components(
id int identity primary key,
producto   int,
componente int ,
cantidad int
)
```

Inserte los tres productos de tu ejemplo , con precios parecidos
en componentes inserte para el producto 1 cantidad 1 del producto 3
y para el producto 2 , cantidad 2 del producto 3
el producto 3 cuesta 600 de costo entonces en la consulta los resultados deben ser para el producto 1, un costo de 600 y para el producto 2 costo de 1200

la consulta deberia ser asi:

```
select c.producto , sum(cantidad * cost ) 
from   components c inner join products p on p.id = c.componente
group by c.producto
```

luego de eso si puedes hacer el update con la consulta de arriba como subconsulta para obtener el valor a asignar en el set.

comenta cual es el evento que mencionas que hará que los valores se actualicen, generalmente utilizo los trigger after update para este tipo de acciones.

Comment: Te comento lo de los triggers porque en la consulta que publicaste realizas un update sin where, y eso puede tener un costo altisimo para el motor

Answer (score 1):

Debe existir la consulta que lo haga todo, pero mientras... esta fue mi solución:

**Consulta 1**. consulta que entrega los productos que contienen el componente modificado.

```
SELECT prd_comp_prd_id, prd_comp_comp_id FROM adm_products_components WHERE prd_comp_comp_id=31
```

**Consulta 2**. consulta que entrega el costo total de cada producto

```
SELECT 
    prd_comp_qty,
    prd_pricecost,
    SUM(prd_comp_qty * prd_pricecost) AS total_Cost
FROM
    adm_products_components
        INNER JOIN
    adm_products ON prd_comp_comp_id = prd_id
WHERE
    prd_comp_prd_id = prd_comp_prd_id;
```

**Consulta 3**. Actualiza el costo de los productos uno a uno

```
UPDATE adm_products SET prd_pricecost = total_Cost WHERE prd_id = prd_comp_prd_id LIMIT 1;
```

**Consulta 4**. Si se elimina el componente, este se quita de los productos que lo contienen. Solo cuando se elimina de la tabla

```
DELETE FROM adm_products_components WHERE prd_comp_comp_id = 31
```

Y se ejecutan las consultas 1, 2 y 3 para actualizar el costo de los productos

Answer (score 0):

Si tu consulta funcionara, estarías estableciendo el precio de coste de todos los productos al mismo que el del 28.

Prueba así y, en una única consulta, actualizarás los costes todos los productos:

```
UPDATE adm_products JOIN (
    SELECT prd_comp_prd_id prd_id,
      SUM(prd_comp_qty * prd_pricecost) totalCost
      FROM adm_products_components
      JOIN adm_products ON prd_comp_prd_id = prd_id
      GROUP BY 1  
  ) c1 USING(prd_id)
  set prd_pricecost=totalCost;
```

Probablemente tengas que ejecutarla varias veces hasta que se actualicen todas las dependencias.

Aporto el dataset por si alguien lo necesitara para comprobar la consulta:

```
CREATE TABLE adm_products(
  prd_id int,
  prd_name varchar(127),
  prd_pricesell1 float,
  prd_pricecost float
  );
CREATE TABLE adm_products_components(
  prd_comp_id int,
  prd_comp_prd_id int,
  prd_comp_comp_id int,
  prd_comp_qty float
  );
```